# How to gettext from django.contrib.auth

Tags: django

I am working on translate my Django app, But there are some messages text don't appear in django.po like:

- **This password is too common.**
- **A user with that username already exists.**
- **The password is too similar to the email address.**

and they from **`django.contrib.auth`**

i did run **`django-admin makemessages -l **`**

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: These are normally already translated in the translation files of `django.contrib.auth`. You should only translate the messages of the apps you are constructing.

Comment: The one and only @WillemVanOnsem thanks you. i just remember i did delete the folder ```django.contrib.auth.locale``` i get sick of all django.po files shown in search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank to @WillemVanOnsem [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72388320/how-to-gettext-from-django-contrib-auth#comment127882721_72388320) i remember i did delete the
folder  `django.contrib.auth.locale` so i copy it form other project.